# ALLOWED_HOSTS and CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS don't work on VPS

Tags: django, angular, docker, django-rest-framework, vps

I have project on VPS with front-end (Angular) and back-end (Django, DRF). VPS is running on Ubuntu 22.04 and has nginx. I used docker with compose to build images and run containers.

Docker works fine on VPS and if I try to get to ip-address:8081 or <domain_name:8081> I see my Angular page and other links. But if try to get port 8082 (this is where back-end is listening, see the `docker-compose` below) I see error `DisallowedHost at /`, `Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'ip-address'. You may need to add 'ip-address' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.`

I added everything that I found from other topics. For now I have smth like that in `settings.py`:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', 'ip:8082', '127.0.0.1', 'domain_name:8082', '*',]

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:8081', # This is to allow requests from Angular app
]
```

but it doesn't work even when I try to rebuild images, containers and volumes. I think that's the reason why Angular can't connect to django and daphne (websocket, channels).

P.S. it works locally in docker and without. If the problem can be related to `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS`, write about it too. I don't use nginx as proxy, request filter. But I have such nginx configuration in `etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` file:

```
server {
        listen                8080;
        root                  /var/www/www-root/data;
        index                 index.html;
        server_name           _;

        location / {                                                                                                 
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                proxy_pass http://ip-address:8082;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
}
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

services:
  # Back-end
  django:
    build:
      context: ./back-end
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    image: django-image
    volumes:
      - backend_code:/api
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8082
    container_name: django
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    
  # Websocket
  daphne:
    image: django-image
    volumes:
      - backend_code:/api
    command: daphne -p 8001 -b 0.0.0.0 api.asgi:application
    container_name: daphne
    depends_on:
      - django
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"

  # Front-end
  angular:
    build:
      context: ./front-end
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    image: angular-image
    command: ng serve --port 8081 --host 0.0.0.0
    container_name: angular
    depends_on:
      - django
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"

volumes:
  backend_code:
```

Comment: http://.127.0.0.1
add this in your CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS

Comment: Didn't help. maybe I use wrong ip-addresses in docker-compose or `settings.py`.

Comment: Replace 'your_vps_ip' with the actual IP address of your VPS and 'your_domain_name'. Note: make sure to restart the django application too. hope so it will work or it should be

Comment: Added `http://ip-of-vps` and `http://domain-name-on-vps` without ports to CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS in `settings.py` but it still doesn't work. When I build and run containers I get the same error in terminal and also this: `Bad Request: /
django   | [07/Dec/2023 16:01:08] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 60238
django   | [07/Dec/2023 16:01:08] code 505, message Invalid HTTP version (2.0)
django   | [07/Dec/2023 16:01:08] "PRI * HTTP/2.0" 505 -
`